# Handling jQuery click events inside a table

Tags: jquery, textbox, click, row

I have a table that contains several rows each containing one button and one textbox.

What is the simplest way to trigger alert with a textbox value?

Comment: textbox? textarea you mean? alert on what action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bind a click handler to the button which traverses up the DOM to its containing `<tr>`, and then finds the textbox from there:

```
// Bind a click handler to all buttons in the table...
$('table :button').click(function () {

  var text = $(this)    // "this" is the button which was clicked
    .closest('tr')      // find the <tr> which contains it...
    .find(':text')      // find the text box within that <tr>...
    .val();             // and get its value

  alert(text);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If the text-input and the button are the only two in a row (`<tr>`) then you can use an event handler like this:

```
$('#table_id').delegate('a', function () {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').val());
});
```

If the button is a form element, you can replace the `'a'` selector with `'input[type="button"]'`.